# Adding jQuery plugins in Liferay

Tags: jquery, liferay

I'm using Liferay 5.0.
It includes the jQuery by default.
The problem is that I want to add some jQuery plugins.

The questions are :

Where should I put them ? in the Javascript folder?
Then how should I call them? 
Is there a clean way to do the whole operation?

I tried to include them in the "javascript" folder then calling them in the "portal_normal.vm" but it doesn't work.

Thank you,

Regards.

Answer (score 2):

place all javascript in the js folder

you can include js in your portal_normal.vm by placing this between your headtags

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="$javascript_folder/jquery.dropdown.js"></script>
```

Comment: The '$javascript_folder' part of the file path is exactly what I was missing.
Thank you for posting this!